# Managing Many-To-Many Relationships in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, many-to-many

I'm trying to manage some simple lists in a many-to-many relationship at the *application level*. I'm looking to update the relationship in both objects everytime a connection is made between them (e.g `teacher.AddStudent()`, `student.RemoveTeacher()`).

I'm aware that if I was using SQL, I'd be using something like `StudentTeacher` table to manage the relationships, but I'm trying to understand how to do this within the application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace StudentTeacher
{
    // create simple interface
    public interface IPerson {}

    // abstract class
    public abstract class Person : IPerson 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    // concrete "Teacher"
    public class Teacher : Person
    {
        // private list of student ids
        private List<int> _studentIds { get; set; }

        // readonly accessor
        public ReadOnlyCollection<int> StudentIds {
            get { return _studentIds.AsReadOnly(); }
        }

        // constructor
        public Teacher(int id) {
            Id = id;
            _studentIds = new List<int>();    
        }

        // add a student
        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (!_studentIds.Contains(student.Id)) {
                _studentIds.Add(student.Id);
                student.AddTeacher(this);
            }
        }

        // remove a student
        public void RemoveStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (_studentIds.Contains(student.Id)) {
                _studentIds.Remove(student.Id);
                student.RemoveTeacher(this);
            }
        }

        public string ToString() {
            return String.Format("Id:{0} | StudentIds:{1}", Id, String.Join(",", StudentIds));
        }
    }

    /// concrete "Student"
    public class Student : Person
    {

        // private list of teacher ids
        private List<int> _teacherIds { get; set; }

        // readonly accessor
        public ReadOnlyCollection<int> TeacherIds {
            get { return _teacherIds.AsReadOnly(); }
        }

        // constructor
        public Student(int id) {
            Id = id;
            _teacherIds = new List<int>();    
        }

        // add a teacher
        public void AddTeacher(Teacher teacher)
        {
            if (!_teacherIds.Contains(teacher.Id)) {
                _teacherIds.Add(teacher.Id); 
                teacher.AddStudent(this);
            }
        }

        // remove teacher
        public void RemoveTeacher(Teacher teacher)
        {
            if (_teacherIds.Contains(teacher.Id)) {
                _teacherIds.Remove(teacher.Id);
                teacher.RemoveStudent(this);
            }
        }

        // simple override
        public string ToString() {
            return String.Format("Id:{0} | TeacherIds:{1}", Id, String.Join(",", TeacherIds));
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create teachers
            var teacher1 = new Teacher(101);
            var teacher2 = new Teacher(102);

            // create students
            var student1 = new Student(501);
            var student2 = new Student(502);
            var student3 = new Student(503);

            // create some relationships
            teacher1.AddStudent(student1);
            teacher1.AddStudent(student2);
            teacher1.AddStudent(student3);

            // see what's happening
            Console.WriteLine(teacher1.ToString()); // "Id:101 | StudentIds:501,502,503"
            Console.WriteLine(student1.ToString()); // "Id:501 | TeacherIds:101"
            Console.WriteLine(student2.ToString()); // "Id:502 | TeacherIds:101"
            Console.WriteLine(student3.ToString()); // "Id:503 | TeacherIds:101"

            // update student1, student2
            student1.AddTeacher(teacher2);
            student2.AddTeacher(teacher2);

            // -- Outputs 
            Console.WriteLine(student1.ToString()); // "Id:501 | TeacherIds:101,102"
            Console.WriteLine(student2.ToString()); // "Id:502 | TeacherIds:101,102"

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

To me, it doesn't feel right to call opposite direction add/remove methods directly;

```
if (!_studentIds.Contains(student.Id)) {
    _studentIds.Add(student.Id);
    student.AddTeacher(this); // calling this directly feels bad
}
```

I have a feeling that this could get really messy quite quickly. My questions are;

- Should I be looking to add something like a static observer such as
  `StudentTeacherObserver` and raise events on that instead, e.g.
  `OnTeacherAdded`, `OnStudentAdded`?
- Is there a particular pattern for managing such relationships?
- Is there a better data structure suited for this purpose, if so, what is it and how do I use it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you don't want an established ORM to handle all of this for you?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Because I want to learn how to do it for myself.

Comment: Why would things get messy? The only mess there is, is the one you have at the moment, and it is contained well and encapsulated nicely. What sort of problems do you foresee?

Comment: By making your classes observable (as you suggested in the question) you'd be adding a bunch of unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @YoryeNathan / caesay Perhaps I am overthinking this too much. This does work, but I guess I'm asking is there any gotchas to this approach?

Comment: Well, you would have to remove yourself from the other object's list when destroying yourself, otherwise you wouldn't get disposed. And when I say you, I mean `this`. Also, I would check for null objects when adding, and you might also want to know that `Remove` returns a boolean that indicates whether the item has been found and removed, so you don't need to check `Contains`. Other than that, you're good to go.

Comment: If you insist, though, you could have a SchoolManager class or something, which has dictionaries of Student to Teachers and Teacher to Students, and encapsulates the add and remove issues. It might even be more logical, since I doubt teachers remember all their students (and sometimes vise versa), but the school surely has everything documented. :P

Comment: Good point about the disposing of `this` from the other object list. Surely I'd have to check using `Contains` to avoid duplicates? I do think that a `SchoolManager` might be better to apply other business logic perhaps when a student is added to teacher... e.g. if the number of students is greater than 30, assign a classroom. (random example)

Comment: I'm talking about remove only here, not add. Instead of checking Contains, and if true, remove and call other object, you could check if remove, and if true call other object. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Nested object graphs (`Teacher.Students[0].Teacher...`) can often feel "messy" particularly when deciding between lazy loading the relations (chatty) or loading all the objects up front, then mapping the references (fatty).

I don't think you're over-thinking it, though. Many-to-Many are difficult to properly represent without making some type of concession with the data access. I think you'll need to evaluate your business problem a little deeper to discover more specific scenarios to determine if you need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is pick a winner.  So don't implement both scenarios.  Here is a link with a little bit of background:

http://www.ebenroux.co.za/post/2009/09/09/Many-to-Many-Aggregate-Roots.aspx

You'll have to come up with what works for you.  Having real objects represented also is not always a good idea.  Simply storing the relevant ID may be enough.  In the `Order`/`OrderItem` to `Product` example.  There is probably no reason to have an actual `Product` object in the `OrderItem` as it is not part of the `Order` aggregate.  You are only using data from the `Product` after which it becomes denormalized state on the `OrderItem`.  Up until the point that the `Order` is actioned (someone actually starts filling the `Order`) it can be changed.  Of course, the business rules about stopping the process (canceling the order) and returning products, etc., can be hairy but that changes from one situation/business to the next.

The point is to attempt to 'cut' your object graph so that you have clearly defined aggregates.

This helps with the lazy-loading bit.  I never use lazy-loading and would urge anyone I meet to do their utmost to avoid it.  The idea is really not to query your object/domain model but that is another discussion altogether.

I hope this makes sense :)